# Catch timeout event in ruby selenium

Tags: ruby, testing, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

Is there any way to catch all timeout error events in selenium , written in Ruby?

I am writing jenkins with selenium , but not sure the best way to terminate building tasks btw steps . The way I found so far is to put exec("exit 1") inside ruby file. However, I have no idea when to put this command . So , I'd like to catch all timeout error and trigger this event.

If there's any better way , please kindly advise !
Thanks!

Comment: Is it for selenium-webdriver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some hints to your problem:

```
begin

    wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) # seconds
    wait.until { driver.title.include? "page title" }
    driver.find_element(:xpath, ".//*[@id='subTabHeaders']/div[3]")}.click

rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::TimeOutError

    exit(1)

end
```